# Juniper AX411 access points and 2.4ghz

Tags: juniper, access-point

I'm using the Juniper AX411 access points in my office. I have set them up to broadcast 3 different virtual access points all over 2.4 ghz. This all works fine for maybe 1-2 days and then this slows down to a halt till no one else can connect to the ap.

I look at the neighbours and i see around 40 different access points broadcasting on all different channels on the 2.4 ghz range. Am i just getting interference which is killing my network?

I am planning to enable 5ghz all access points which will work for all our desktops and laptops but will not work for any phones.

What options do i have to try and prevent the 2.4ghz network dieing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With that many nearby access points, you will have some issues.  Are all channels being used?  Is your AP set to automatically selct a channel or have you set one manually?

Can you change the antennas for ones with more gain?   This may just result in an escalation from the nearby AP users but could make for a better signal for your AP and users

Comment: They were set to automatic. I set 2 out of the 4 access points to a manual channel today so was going to see if that helps. I have also lowered the transmit power down to 40% which reaches more than enough to cover its area. If i increase to 100% is this going to cause more problems clashing with each other?

Comment: Lowering power to the minimum needed really is a good thing. Automatic channel assignment is often ok these days, but manual assignment can be better if you measure what's out there (for this there are many pc/android apps that will tell you what channels are best), remember to have each AP on a separate channel or they will interfere.